# Bitrise Xamarin build fails with message "No exportable output found"

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.ios, bitrise

I'm trying to setup my first custom Xamarin IOS build on Bitrise. i manage to have the sample app building. I tried to create a build for a custom IOS single page app and I'm getting the same error.

```
["\"/Applications/Xamarin Studio.app/Contents/MacOS/mdtool\"", "build", "\"-c:Debug|iPhoneSimulator\"", "\"tamtammeapp.sln\"", "\"-p:TamTamMe.IOS\""]
Xamarin Studio Build Tool
Loading solution: /Users/vagrant/git/tamtammeapp.sln
Loading projects ..
Building: TamTamMe.IOS (Debug|iPhoneSimulator)
generated_files: {"{AE5511D0-5224-4AC5-B25F-BDFB1851FB67}"=>{:app=>"./TamTamMe.IOS/bin/iPhoneSimulator/Debug/TamTamMe.IOS.app", :api=>"ios"}}
No exportable output found
```

I cannot figure out what I'm doing wrong. Any idea?

Thanks,

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The step [xamarin-builder](https://github.com/bitrise-steplib/steps-xamarin-builder) is expected to generete platform specific archives (.APK file for Android, .ipa file for iOS, .pkg/.app for Mac), the error means building your project with given configuration:

- platform: `iPhoneSimulator`
- configuration: `Debug`

does not generate .ipa file.

Most of the times, platform: `iPhone` generates .ipa as output, so try to change the platform (but it depends on your project settings).

Check out your ios project settings by double cliking on your project, in the project navigator, select *iOS Build* tab in the *Project Options* menu, *Under Code Generation & Runtime* you can find *Supported arhictectures*, **xamarin-builder** step will generated .ipa for configuration-platform combination, where architecture is ARMx.

Comment: Thanks. Indeed I had not specified a target platform. I specified ios and then the build worked as expected.